# Absolute email address on Jekyll

Tags: email, relative-path, jekyll, absolute-path, email-address

I am writing the contact page of my blog. When I put the email address in markdown format

```
[contact me] (myname@gmail.com)
```

Jekyll sees the email address as a relative path and auto-completes it to localhost:4000/myname@gmail.com locally or https://usr.github.com/myname@gmail.com when pushed to github, which leads to an unable-to-find page. In contrast, if the email address is left as it is, the address should be opened by a mail client.

Is there a way to force the email address to be absolute (disable auto-completion) or are there other workarounds?

I searched and didn't find a solution. I'll appreciate your kind help with this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured out the question with [Markdown Documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). It turns out not to be a jekyll problem but a MarkDown one. I replaced the line

```
[contact me] (myname@gmail.com)
```

with

```html
<a href="mailto:myname@gmail.com">contact me</a>
```

and the problem was resolved.

Probably the **mailto:** link is some common sense but it did trap me for a while.

Answer (score 18):

The correct Markdown syntax for creating an email links is:

```
[contact me](mailto:myname@gmail.com)
```

Comment: This should be marked correct. Clearly the `markdown` way to do things.